# JavaScript Sticky Footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm using this JS to sticky website footers at the bottom and I would like to know if is there anything to be optimised?

```
(function($, window, document){
    //Screen_height = Header_height + Main_Content_height + Footer_height + alltoplvlContainersMarginTop_Bottom + alltoplvlContainersPaddingTop_Bottom
    $.fn.sticky_footer = function(header,footer,content) {
        if(typeof header != undefined && typeof footer != undefined && typeof content != undefined) {
            var screen_height = $(window).height(); //Total height of the screen which is rendered within a browser window without having to scroll-down.

            var sum_of_top_bottom_props = function(id){ //Returns the sum of float values of padding-top,bottom margin-top,bottom, border-top,bottom-width.
                    if(typeof id != undefined){
                        var elem_id = id;
                        if(elem_id.length>0) { //If id exists in the page, fetch the sum of float values of the properties.
                           var prop_padding = parseFloat(elem_id.css('padding-top'))+parseFloat(elem_id.css('padding-bottom')),
                               prop_margin = parseFloat(elem_id.css('margin-top'))+parseFloat(elem_id.css('margin-bottom')),
                               prop_border = parseFloat(elem_id.css('border-top-width'))+parseFloat(elem_id.css('border-bottom-width'));
                           return prop_padding+prop_margin+prop_border;
                       } else{ //If id soesnot exist return 0;
                           console.error("The id: "+id+" doesn't exists! Pleas enter a valid id.");
                           return 0;
                       }
                   }};

            var header_height = (header.length>0) ? header.height():0, //Height of header
                footer_height = (footer.length>0) ? footer.height():0, //Height of footer
                header_props = sum_of_top_bottom_props(header), //Height of properties that contribute to header's height.
                footer_props = sum_of_top_bottom_props(footer), //Height of properties that contribute to footer's height.
                main_props = sum_of_top_bottom_props(content), //Height of properties that contribute to content's height.
                main_height = screen_height-(header_height + header_props + main_props + footer_props + footer_height);

            if(content!= undefined && content.length>0) { content.css('min-height',main_height); return true; } 
            else return false;
        } 
        else return false;
    }
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

GitHub: https://github.com/Elavarasanlee/sticky-footer.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a once over,

- I strongly suggest lowerCamelCase: `sticky_footer` -> `stickyFooter`, `screen_height` -> `screenHeight` etc. etc.
- You should compare to `undefined` with `===` or use a falsey comparison, I would suggest the falsey comparison:

  ```
  if(header && footer && content) {
  ```
- This: `var elem_id = id;` makes no sense to me, why not simply keep working with `id` ?
- If you are going to return the sum of all 6 css values (`return prop_padding+prop_margin+prop_border;` ), then I would not use the temporary values but just return the actual calculation
- Do not use `console.log` in production code
- That gives something like this:

  ```
  //Returns the sum of float values of padding-top/bottom,margin-top/bottom, border-top/bottom, 
  //if no element is provided, returns 0
  var sum_of_top_bottom_props = function(id){ 
      if(id && id.length){
          return parseFloat(elem_id.css('padding-top')) + 
                 parseFloat(elem_id.css('padding-bottom')) +
                 parseFloat(elem_id.css('margin-top')) + 
                 parseFloat(elem_id.css('margin-bottom')) +
                 parseFloat(elem_id.css('border-top-width')) + 
                 parseFloat(elem_id.css('border-bottom-width'));
       }
       return 0;
  }};
  ```
- `else return false` is pointless, just do `return false`
- Finally, you require the user of your script to take care of `$(window).resize(function(){`, your script should take care of that instead.